# Java watch two directories using two different Watch Services

Tags: java

I have a working implementation of a directory watcher which recursively registers itself and subdirectories for a given path.

The issue I am having is I have specific behaviours syncing behaviours to perform on separate directories and to prevent it becoming really messy I would like to instantiate an instance of my `DirectoryWatcher` and pass it an instance of my `Syncer` class which will be able to deduce the correct behaviour.

The Issue I am having is I cannot create two instances of my directory watch class because only the first one instantiated actually watches the directory.

Code snippets:

```
private final WatchService watcher;
private final Map<WatchKey, Path> keys;
private final boolean recursive;
private boolean trace = false;
private final Syncer syncer;

public DirectoryWatcher(Path dir, boolean recursive, Syncer syncer) throws IOException {
        this.syncer = syncer;
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey, Path>();
        this.recursive = recursive;

        if (recursive) {
            logger.info("Watching Directory {} ...", dir);
            registerAll(dir);
            logger.info("Registered Directory {} ...", dir);
        } else {
            register(dir);
        }
        // enable trace after initial registration
        this.trace = true;
    }
```

Creating a single instance (works):

```
 new DirectoryWatcher(path, true, new Syncer(path, path2, "some extra key")).processEvents();
```

Output:

```
[main] INFO Controller.directory.DirectoryWatcher - Watching Directory /some/path ...
[main] INFO Controller.directory.DirectoryWatcher - Registered Directory /some/path ...
```

Attempting to have multiple instances:

```
 new DirectoryWatcher(path, true, new Syncer(path, path2, "some extra key")).processEvents();
 new DirectoryWatcher(path2, true, new Syncer(path2, path, "some extra key part 2")).processEvents();
```

Output:

```
[main] INFO Controller.directory.DirectoryWatcher - Watching Directory /some/path ...
[main] INFO Controller.directory.DirectoryWatcher - Registered Directory /some/path ...
```

It never seems to watch the second directory (`path2`).

I can register multiple paths on the same instance but that's not the functionality I am after.

I also tried putting the watcher inside a `runnable.run()` but the same problem persisted.

Edit:

Adding `register` and `registerAll` methods:

```
private void registerAll(final Path start) throws IOException {
        // register directory and sub-directories
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                    throws IOException {
                register(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }

  private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
        WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        if (trace) {
            Path prev = keys.get(key);
            if (prev == null) {
                logger.info("Register: {}", dir);
            } else {
                if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
//                    System.out.format("update: %s -> %s\n", prev, dir);
                    logger.info("Update: {} -> {}", prev, dir);
                }
            }
        }
        keys.put(key, dir);
    }
```

Edit 2: Added `processEvents()`

```
 public void processEvents() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (; ; ) {
            WatchKey key;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                return;
            }

            Path dir = keys.get(key);
            if (dir == null) {
                logger.error("WatchKey not recognized!!");
                continue;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
                Path name = ev.context();
                Path child = dir.resolve(name);

//                System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);
                syncer.sync(child);

                // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
                // register it and its sub-directories
                if (recursive && (kind == ENTRY_CREATE)) {
                    try {
                        if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                            registerAll(child);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException x) {
                        // ignore to keep sample readbale
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you add the `register` and `registerAll` methods?

Comment: I suspect the `processEvents` method contains an endless loop - could you elaborte on this method?

Comment: Updated. Yes the process Events does contain an endless loop, This is to always keep the watcher open untill i close the application (is there another way). Wouldn't creating two instances in separate `runnable.run()` methods just make two endless loops?

Comment: Creating the two instances in two threads will create two endless loops - but that is exactly what threads are built for: to do two things in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it correctly you are instantiating both `DirectoryWatchers` in the same thread?!

If this is true, it's no wonder that the second instance is never started as the thread remains executing the endless `processEvents` loop of the first watcher. You'll have to start both watchers in separate threads in order to be executed in parallel. You could for example instantiate an `ExecutorService` and submit your runnables to this service:

```
final DirectoryWatcher watcher1 = new DirectoryWatcher(path, true,
        new Syncer(path, path2, "some extra key"));
final DirectoryWatcher watcher2 = new DirectoryWatcher(path2, true,
        new Syncer(path2, path, "some extra key part 2"));

final ExecutorService tExecutorService = Executors
        .newCachedThreadPool();
tExecutorService.submit(watcher1::processEvents);
tExecutorService.submit(watcher2::processEvents);
```

Simply putting the code inside a `Runnable` won't execute both `Runnables` in parallel...